# Run javascript on WizardStep activation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to run some javascript code after particular WizardStep becomes active:

```
<asp:WizardStep ID="wsPaymentMethods" runat="server">

   <!-- some markup goes here -->

   <script type="text/javascript">
       alert('Outer alert');
       Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
           alert('Page loaded alert');
       });
   </script>
</asp:WizardStep>
```

But in fact none of these alerts has shown. Is that behaviour "by design" or this is some kind of bug?

For now, i'm doing thigs that way:

```
protected void OrderWizard_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OrderWizard.ActiveStep == wsPaymentMethods)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "customerFormInit", "customerFormInit()", true);
    }
}
```

But i'm just wondering why the js code inside WizardStep does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

you can run the js function on ActiveStepChanged event with a check on active step index like

```
if(e.ActiveStepIndex==X)
{
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("scripidentifier","your script or call js function");
}
```

Comment: That's how i doing right now. But it seems srange to me, how the js code does just nothing.